# Selecting continuous elements in jquery li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select elements continuously inside my li
e.g.1 to 5 i.e. first 5 elements or 2 to 9 elements from 2 to 9
So, basically my requirement is to select n number of elements starting from the given element which is clicked. 
//here is my jquery method which helps me select only 1 element in li

```js
$('.timeslots li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  selectedStartTime = $(this).text();
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="timeslots">
  <li class="leftarrow"> &nbsp;</li>
  <li> 01: 00</li>
  <li> 01: 30</li>
  <li> 02: 00</li>
  <li> 02: 30</li>
  <li> 03: 00</li>
  <li> 03: 30</li>
  <li> 04: 00</li>
  <li> 04: 30</li>
  <li> 05: 00</li>
  <li> 05: 30</li>
  <li> 06: 00</li>
  <li class="rightarrow">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "select" exactly?

Comment: @JerdineSabio I mean if I click on the element the color should change to that which I have added in the css file. The selected class in my code refers to the color. So my requirement is I want to select n number of elements continuously once i click on any element

Comment: Nope, I want to click 2nd element and I want 3 elements to be selected, so when I click on 2nd element 2,3 and 4 will be selected automatically based on where I start from. It based on the input which I'm going to pass. If I pass 5 as input and I click on the 3rd element 3,4,5,6,7 should be selected. If I click on 1st element again  then 1,2,3,4,5 should be selected

Answer (score 1):

Basically if you want to select `n` elements from the one you click try this:

- Get the index of your actual element
- Select based on that index and the amount of elements you want to be selected.

```js
$('.timeslots li').on('click', function() {
  const amountToSelect = 3;
  const listCollection = $('.timeslots li')
  const indexElement = listCollection.index($(this))
  listCollection.removeClass('selected')

  listCollection.slice(indexElement, indexElement+amountToSelect).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="timeslots">
  <li class="leftarrow"> &nbsp;</li>
  <li> 01: 00</li>
  <li> 01: 30</li>
  <li> 02: 00</li>
  <li> 02: 30</li>
  <li> 03: 00</li>
  <li> 03: 30</li>
  <li> 04: 00</li>
  <li> 04: 30</li>
  <li> 05: 00</li>
  <li> 05: 30</li>
  <li> 06: 00</li>
  <li class="rightarrow">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's classy with the .slice()

Comment: @JerdineSabio but you have not used slice() in the solution which you have provided

Answer (score 0):

1. Use .index() to store the index of the clicked element
2. Define number of steps
3. Loop through number of steps from the index

```js
$('.timeslots li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  selectedStartTime = $(this).text();

  // store the index of clicked element to a variable
  var clickedIndex = $(this).index();

  // define number of steps you want
  var desiredSteps = 5;

  // loop from the index + number of steps
  for (i = 1; i < desiredSteps; i++) {
    $(".timeslots li").eq(clickedIndex + i).addClass("selected");
  }
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="timeslots">
  <li class="leftarrow"> &nbsp;</li>
  <li> 01: 00</li>
  <li> 01: 30</li>
  <li> 02: 00</li>
  <li> 02: 30</li>
  <li> 03: 00</li>
  <li> 03: 30</li>
  <li> 04: 00</li>
  <li> 04: 30</li>
  <li> 05: 00</li>
  <li> 05: 30</li>
  <li> 06: 00</li>
  <li class="rightarrow">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```